# Find a basis for the following set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm unsure of how to find a basis for the set of vectors $\left(x,y,z\right)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $z=2x-5y$

I understand that you can prove vectors form a basis by showing they are linearly independent and spanning, but I don't know to find one.

Comment: That equation defines a plane, do you know how to find the normal to the plane?

Answer (score 1):

Any vector $(x,y,z)$ satisfying $z=2x-5y$ can be written as
$$(x,y,2x-5y) = (x,0,2x)+(0,y,-5y) = x(1,0,2)+y(0,1,-5)$$
so it can be written as a linear combination of the vectors $(1,0,2)$ and $(0,1,-5)$. Consequently, the subspace is spanned by $\left\{ (1,0,2),(0,1,-5) \right\}$. Check if these two vectors are linearly independent; if so, then they form a basis.

Since the equation defines a plane (through the origin) in $\mathbb{R}^3$, you may find it logical that a basis contains two elements - why?